# Splitting text in textarea by new lines (including empty lines) into javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split, newline

I'm trying to split the text inside Splitting textarea data by new lines. My current code works, except for a small requirement: The resulting array **must include empty lines** as well.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var lines = [];
    $.each($('#data').val().split(/\n/), function(i, line){
        if(line){
            lines.push(line);
        }
    });
    console.log(lines);
});
</script>


<textarea id="data">
I like to eat icecream. Dogs are fast.

The previous line is composed by spaces only.



The last 3 lines are empty.

One last line.
</textarea>
```

The current result is:

> ["I like to eat icecream. Dogs are fast.", "    ", "The previous line is composed by spaces only.", "The last 3 lines are empty.", "One last line."]

What it **should** be:

> ["I like to eat icecream. Dogs are fast.", "    ", "The previous line is composed by spaces only.", "", "", "", "The last 3 lines are empty.", "", "One last line."]

Comment: Does the simple split not do what you ask? Your `each` function removes all empty lines.

Comment: @HBP I didn't know that `\n` wouldn't return `false/null`. It has been fixed as per the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `.split` will include \n, but when `line` is falsey you can just push an empty string...

```
$(function(){
    var lines = [];
    $.each($('#data').val().split(/\n/), function(i, line){
        if(line){
            lines.push(line);
        } else {
            lines.push("");
        }
    });
    console.log(lines);
});
```

Here is a working example : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o9utz2Lo/2/)

**Output:**

```
["I like to eat icecream. Dogs are fast.", 
"",  "The previous line is composed by spaces only.",  
"",  "",  "", 
"The last 3 lines are empty.",  
"",  "One last line."]
```

Or simply as comment above suggests (I had assumed that your example had been simplified and you need to do something else in the `.each` loop):

```
var lines = $('#data').val().split(/\n/);
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o9utz2Lo/3/)

Comment: Worked great, thanks! I didn't know that `\n` wouldn't return `false/null`.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to geedubb's answer if you prefer to avoid using the backslash for encoding reasons:

```
var lines = $('#data').val().split(String.fromCharCode(10));
```