# Add line breaks to textarea field when submitting form with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, get

```
   <form onsubmit="location.href='https://www.example.com/test/?message=' + document.getElementById('message').value; return false;">
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="5" cols="50">
    </textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
```

If I make three lines of text in the textarea:

```
AAA
BBB 
CCC
```

..it will return the url like this:

```
https://www.example.com/test/?message=AAABBBCCC
```

I want to add linebreaks to the string in the url, so I can separate the values.

Answer (score 0):

Why not split by new line char? Or replace new line char with special char and parse on the server/frontend?

[Splitting text in textarea by new lines (including empty lines) into javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241954/splitting-text-in-textarea-by-new-lines-including-empty-lines-into-javascript)